# How many tables can you put in one windows azure storage account?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

The documentation I see says that there can be "Many" tables in one storage account.

Does anyone actually know the limit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no limit on the number of tables you can create in one storage account. The limit comes in terms of a storage account size. **A single Windows Azure storage account can hold `200 TB` of data**. As long as you're under that size limit, you'll be good.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, that is what I needed to know.